white and read table from hive/spark thrift server and delta via ODBC
Hi everyone I have an issue and I need help please
here is my env
spark 3.2
hive 2.3.9
and delta-core: 2.0.0
Simba 2.7

I'm tring to run some sql request using spark thrift serve via odbc pyodbc to get data stored in azure blob storage in delta format.
When I create table with
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(con_str)
cs = conn.cursor()
cs.execute("create table test_tb (id INT)")


table is created in default database an I can get into it with select * from default.test_tb
When I run
cs.execute("create database test_db")
cs.execute("create table test_db.mytab")


db and table are created and visible in azure blob storage but when I run
cs.execute("select * table test_db.mytab")

I'm getting this error :
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', '[42S02] [Simba][SQLEngine] (31740) Table or view not found: .test_db.mytab (31740) (SQLExecDirectW)')

How can I solve this error
Thank you

which database management system you're using?

I think you need to call <pyodbc connect>.commit() after calling cs.execute(<query>) methods in order for the changes to be made in the database. Afterwards, you can execute select queries on the database/table. In your code, it would look something like below
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(con_str)
cs = conn.cursor()
cs.execute("create database test_db")
cs.execute("create table test_db.mytab")
cs.commit()
cs.execute("select * table test_db.mytab")

